# How to exclude watermark overlay in last 5sec of video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How to exclude "last 5 seconds of video or last 30x5 frames" from overlay where input video duration is unknown? I have checked enable option with between & gte but both need to provide specific time in seconds.

```
ffmpeg -i vidoe.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:10" -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i vidoe.mp4 -copyts -sseof -5 -i vidoe.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay[bg];[bg][1]overlay" -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: Alternatively, use [`ffprobe` to get duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) and use as a scripted variable in [`enable`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) option.

Comment: Also see [How to add my logo for the last 60 seconds in a video with ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/1117704/)